# k8s-ingress to make the application secured with https

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Im have `k8s` app (Web api) which first exposed via `NodePort` (I've used port forwarding to run it and it works as expected)

run it like `localhost:8080/api/v1/users`

Than I've created a `service` with type `LoadBalancer` to expose it outside, which **works as expected**.

e.g. `http://myhost:8080/api/v1/users`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: fzr
  labels:
    app: fzr
    tier: service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 8080
  selector:
    app: fzr
```

Now we need to make it `secure` and after reading about this topic we have decided to use **ingress** for it.

This is what I did

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ctr-ingress
  selector:
    app: fzr
spec:
  ports:
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: https
```

now I want to run it like

`https://myhost:443/api/v1/users`

This is **not working**, im not able to run the application with port `443` as `https`, please advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you are using a yaml template for a type service to deploy your ingress but not correctly.  `targetPort` should be a numeric port, and anyway, I don't think "https" is a correct value (I might be wrong though).

Something like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
type: NodePort
metadata:
  name: fzr-ingress
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: fzr
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 443
    targetPort: 8080
```

Now you have a nodeport service listening on 443 and forwarding the traffic to your fzr pods listening on port 8080.

However, the fact you are listening on port 443 does nothing to secure your app by itself. To encrypt the traffic you need a TLS certificate that you have to make available to the ingress as a `secret`.

If this seems somewhat complicated (because it is) you could look into deploying an Nginx ingress from a [helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nginx-ingress)

In any case your ingress yaml would look something like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  name: gcs-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myhost
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: fzr
          servicePort: 443
        path: /api/v1/users
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - myhost
    secretName: myhosts-tls
```

More info on how to configure this [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#tls)